# Facebook login not working after first time in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented login with facebook in my app and it works perfectly for the first time but after first time it is not working at all. I tried setting breakpoint on onSuccess method but it doesn't stop there. Here is my code for facebook login.
First I initialize it in onCreate method like this

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
```

then I call this method also in onCreate

```
public void LoginViaFacebook() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //  AppSharedPreference.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).setFbAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString());

            final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        if (object.getString("id") != null) {

                            String fbId = object.getString("id");
                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            String imageUrl = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                            int randomPIN = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
                            String password = String.valueOf(randomPIN);
                            String nettype = "2";
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Vivian"));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",fbId));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","valw_umg@yahoo.com"));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nettype",nettype));
                            new FbRegisterAsyncTask().execute();
                            // getLoginTokenViaAPI(fbId);
                            //registerUser(name, name, fbId, password,nettype);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,picture,birthday,link,location");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //AppUtils.showDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.fb_login_cancel));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //AppUtils.showDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.fb_login_error) + exception.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

onActivityResult method

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_FB_IN:
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

and on button click I'm doing this

```
 iv_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ActivityLogin.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "user_location", "email", "user_birthday"));

            //LoginViaFacebook();
        }
    });
```

Comment: found anything @Vivek

Comment: @SagarNayak you have to generate key hash via your code instead of one provided by cmd

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @AmitKumar you need to generate key hash via code for it to work everytime. Keyhash generated from cmd doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After successful login you need to logout from fb before goto next activity, for that use this code to logout from facebook.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: Where did you find it? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: not working even after using logout. after first login and it gives me error and also the error is blank !!!!!!!!!!!!!!